# Choosing between left baising or right baising insertion in B tree of even order

Tags: b-tree

If I opted for left biasing insertion during the initial split of the B-tree, I'm curious whether I'm restricted to using the same approach for subsequent splits or whether I have the flexibility to choose between left and right biasing insertion techniques for each new split.

Edit: I asked bing, and it said I always have a choice. However, when I was watching videos on the internet, they said I have to stick with either left or right-biased insertion throughout the whole tree

Comment: Please explain what "biasing" means in this context.

Comment: So, when we split nodes in binary trees of even order, for example, order 4. By left-biased split I mean, there will 2 keys with the left child and 1 key with the right child, and the third key would go to the parent node.